# Putting output of describe function in table R

Tags: r, describe

```
> structure(dat_de$total_all)
 [1] 11 11  9  6  9 15 10  6 11 10 10  9  7 13  7  5  5  8 10 14  9 10 13  6 10 11 12 22 11  1  7  9 12  7  7 11  9  7 15 10  6 10
[43]  8 10  9  8 14  5 10 12 14  9 10 18  8  8 15

> structure(dat_en$total_all)
 [1] 25 10 12 17 10 11 11  9  9 25 14 10 13 22 13 10 11 15 20 11  9 15  9 14 10 19 10  9  8 14  4 18 16  7 10 13  9 11 12
```

This is my variable "Total_all" in the german and english version. 
I want to put the results of the describe function (see below) of these two variables in a presentable table. Preferably one table for both variables, if that is possible.

```
> describe(dat_de$total_all)
   vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 57 9.81 3.45     10    9.62 2.97   1  22    21 0.73     1.81 0.46
> describe(dat_en$total_all)
   vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 39 12.69 4.69     11   12.24 2.97   4  25    21 1.01     0.61 0.75
```

I'm grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure which library the `describe` function is in [edit: looks like you're using the one from the `psych` package] but you can make a simple, nice looking table using the `kable` function from `knitr`:

```
library(knitr)
library(psych)
de_dat_descr <- data.frame(describe(dat_de$total_all), row.names = "de_dat_descr")
en_dat_descr <- data.frame(describe(dat_en$total_all), row.names = "en_dat_descr")

dat.df <- t(rbind.data.frame(de_dat_descr, en_dat_descr))
kable(dat.df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately this gives me the error, that the row name supplied are the wrong length. Do you know what this is about?

Comment: gotcha - I've edited my answer. In the future, try to provide all the details about any specific functions you're using. I didn't know that `describe` was in the psych package for instance which made answering the question on the first go around harder.